# Как найти точку на расстоянии d от прямой?

Tags: javascript, математика, геометрия

Есть ломаная (задана массивом точек) и нужно найти ломаную, огибающую исходную, наверное более понятно будет на рисунке (синяя - та, которую нужно построить):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е, если построить ломаную по новым точкам, она должна повторять и огибать начальную. По каким формулам можно это посчитать, если задан двумерный массив с точками?

Comment: Вы нарисовали "наивный" пример. А в реальной жизни новая ломаная может самопересекаться. Что тогда делать?

Comment: А с чем возникла проблема? С построением прямой, параллельной отрезку ломаной и находящейся на заданном расстоянии от него? С нахождением точки пересечения двух таких прямых? И учтите - расстояние от такой точки пересечения до общей вершины двух отрезков будет больше заданного расстояния... скруглять надобно.

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого узла `P` найти векторы соседних рёбер и определить единичные нормали `na, nb` к ним, направленные в одну сторону относительно полилинии (пусть она называется внешней).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Построить внешний вектор биссектрисы как сумму нормалей, нормализовать его

```
  bis = na + nb
  bis = bis / Length(bis)
```

Чтобы обеспечить нужное расстояние `d` до новых сегментов, длина биссектрисы `l` должна быть

```
   l = d / Cos(fi/2)
```

где `fi` - угол между нормалями

```
 fi = atan2(crossproduct(na,nb), dotproduct(na,nb))
```

Вариант без тригонометрии:

```
Cos(fi/2) = Sqrt(1+dotproduct(na,nb)) или 

l = d / Sqrt(1+dotproduct(na,nb))
```

И наконец узел новой полилинии:

```
 P' = P + l * bis
```

В общем случае на "огибающей ломаной" даже при отсутствии самопересечений базовой полилинии могут возникнуть петли и т.п. эффекты.